# Angular 4 animation - no animation / duration

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I try to animate an element in Angular 4 in terms of its height. Regardless of whether I use margin-bottom or height as attributes to be changed, the change is done, but without animation, meaning, the height/margin-bottom value is jumping from 200px to 0px immediately, without animation and even without delay (if specified).

Here is my animation code:

```
animations: [
  trigger('ansichtState', [
    state('nurSuche', style({
      'margin-bottom': '200px'
    })),
    state('sucheUndErgebnisse', style({
      'margin-bottom': '0px'
    })),
    transition('nurSuche <=> sucheUndErgebnisse', animate('4000ms'))
  ])
]
```

The template code is:

```
<header [@ansichtState]="currentAnsichtState">&nbsp;</header>
```

`currentAnsichtState` is defined correctly and changed by a separate function.

Also the `margin-bottom` value changes from 200px to 0px it is done immediately (although a duration of 4000ms is specified).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr? I don't see a mistake otherwise

Comment: 'nurSuche <=> sucheUndErgebnisse' shouldn´t it be 'nurSuche => sucheUndErgebnisse'. I never worked with margins in an animation, normaly in this cases translate is beeing used. Would reccomend trying it with translate.

Comment: Interestingly, this seems to be a Safari bug, as it works in Chrome...